# Colorcode License Plate/GetPixel Method

Tags: c#, image-processing, getpixel

I'm working on a License Plate Recognition program in C#.
On this moment I need the ARGB color code of the license plate, which is done, and I need the ARGB code of the letters/numbers of the license plate. I used the GetPixel method to get the ARGB code of the license plate, the problem is the text has not a standard position.

I have the x and y values of the edges of the license plate, that's how I found the ARGB code of the license plate itself.

BTW: this part is not necessary to actually find the text in the license plate, but its a part of our program to obtain the ARGB codes.

Comment: You could use edge detection techniques to find the text's positions. I recommend you to use OpenCV (EmguCV in C#) for image processing. You could use it's functions to find the Contours of the image, It needs a lot of work if you want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: As Jay suggested in his answer, I hope your license plate program was not designed for a malicious purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I probably shouldn't help you. This is probably for a system to automatically send out traffic tickets from one of those spy cameras.

But against my better judgement: You're going to have to scan the image for transitions between colors. There's no direct way to find where the letters and numbers appear in the image. Even if license plates were strictly regular, I doubt they are always perfectly centered, from the same magnification and angle in your images. So you're going to have to start from the edges and look for where the color changes. Of course shadows, dirt, etc could confuse such an algorithm.

Other people have solved this problem already in various OCR programs. You might look for an existing solution rather than re-inventing it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i hope to get some solutions though.